# iphone's safari touchmove event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, safari

i am using jquery and touchmove event but the code is not showing anything in #info

```
$('#movieShow').bind('touchmove',function(e){                   
    e.preventDefault();                 
    $('#info').text(e.touches[0].pageX);
});
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try using `e.originalEvent.touches`:

```
$('#movieShow').bind('touchmove',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
    console.log(touch.pageX);
});
```

I ran into a similar problem when I was playing around with touch events and jquery: http://xavi.co/articles/trouble-with-touch-events-jquery

Comment: hmm, just tried on my ipad... everything seemed to work as expected.  Are you seeing any errors?  Also have you tried checking `e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]`?

Comment: I am trying to detect scroll from touchmove event, but in safari pageY, screenY coordinates of touchmove event are not properly working.
- When I touch and move to down then coordinates (pageY,screenY) value fluctuates, means it's going like 468,473,470,480,477,486,481, It should be consistent, increasing or decreasing so I can detect scroll top or scroll down. 
please help me out.

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 1):

It might be as simple as a mis-named *DIV* id ('`#info`') but can't tell without seeing everything.

Try this, and see if you still get no output:

```
$('#movieShow').bind('touchmove',function(e){                   
    e.preventDefault();                 
    console.log(e.touches[0].pageX);
});
```

(You'll need to turn on *Debug Console* in MobileSafari)

**UPDATE**

So, from your comment you get an error: `'e.touches' is not an object`

In that case try this (not jQuery specific):

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.getElementById('movieShow').addEventListener('touchmove',  function(e){
  console.log(e.touches[0].pageX);
},  false);
```

Comment: I've updated my code. Try that. If it works then you can go from there.