# How to Capture Touch Events with Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, touch

I would like to be able to capture the fact that a user moved their finger through a set of DOM elements on a touch device.  This example works fine on a desktop browser but does not fire all the expected events when viewed in mobile Safari.

Working Plunkr (demonstrates the issue on mobile safari):
http://plnkr.co/edit/J8sfuJ9o6DorMSFlK9v2

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!  This works from a desktop browser but not from mobile Safari.  I would simply like to be able to drag my finger down, across all four letters, and have their events fire.  I thought that touchMove would work in place of mouseMove when running this Plunkr on iOS, but it doesn't.</p>  Current letter: {{currentLetter}}

    <div swipe-over="swipeOver()">A</div>
    <div swipe-over="swipeOver()">B</div>
    <div swipe-over="swipeOver()">C</div>
    <div swipe-over="swipeOver()">D</div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.currentLetter = "";

  $scope.swipeOver = function() {
    $log.info("In swipeOver");
  };
});

app.directive('swipeOver', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // For touch devices
      element.bind("touchmove", function() {
        scope.$apply(function(evt) {
          $log.info("in touchmove - " + element.text());

          scope.$parent.currentLetter = element.text();
        });
      });

      // For desktops
      element.bind("mousemove", function(evt, e2) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            $log.info(evt);
            $log.info(e2);
            $log.info("in mousemove - " + element.text());

            scope.$parent.currentLetter = element.text();
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I have tried the ng-touch library but it does not support vertical touch movements, amazingly.  Any help would be massively appreciated at this point . . .

Comment: Could it be related to this question: [iphones-safari-touchmove-event-not-working][1]?



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531997/iphones-safari-touchmove-event-not-working

Comment: Hi,
i'm having the same problem.
can you please show me how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of touchmove currently, and I'm afraid there's no really good answer.

The best solution is to bind touchmove to a parent element and then calculate which child element is under the current touch point. It's answered in a jQuery context here [Crossing over to new elements during touchmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396635/crossing-over-to-new-elements-during-touchmove).

You'll need to cycle through each of the child elements on the parent and check if the touch point is within their bounds.

Comment: Thank you.  Sad that this was necessary - but thrilled that it worked!

Answer (score -2):

Use Hammer.JS, it's the best I know. Angular-Hammer can be easily modified to support version 2.