# touchmove event has empty event data

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, touchmove

**nevermind** i realize that 'JSON.stringify(evt)' does not print out the data in the event object ????

original question:

i have

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function(evt)
{
  alert(JSON.stringify(evt));
},false);
```

when i see the alert, the 'evt' is blank. so all these posts like this one [iphone's safari touchmove event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531997/iphones-safari-touchmove-event-not-working) that say to get the 'originalEvent' do not apply to me, because there is nothing in the evt at all to see.

How do i get the 'evt' to have touch data in it so that i can get touch locations with code like

```
var touch = evt.changedTouches[0];
```

?

note: The next line of code has the following mouse events which work great

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt)
{
  alert(JSON.stringify(evt));
}, false);
```

Comment: They used the bind method, not addEventListener, the return values are not the same.

Comment: Try to debug your code with some emulator. Output data in console at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data is there, it's just that

```
alert(JSON.stringify(evt));
```

appears blank. not sure why JSON.stringify does not work on events, but that's my take-home messaage