# Touchmove and touchend events are not firing on ios Safari

Tags: javascript, ios

I am making a cheesy little web app to amuse someone's child who is sick. In this app you drill holes into a plank of wood. I'd like the user to be able to move the drill around with their finger or mouse.

I am having trouble getting this code to work on ios Safari. I haven't tested it on other ios browsers, but it works on both my desktop and android phone with firefox 68.2.0 and chrome 83. I don't know what device they will have access to currently, but it could be an iPhone.

On ios, touchmove and touchend are not firing at all. There is a delay between touching the screen and the touchstart events - maybe those are being treated like a mousedown? This is the first time I have tried to use touch events directly, and unfortunately Apple decided not to include dev tools on the iPad (boo).

Here is my html/css - I wouldn't normally combine, but this was supposed to be a quick and dirty little app

```
<script src="drill.js"></script>
<style>
  .drill {
    pointer-events: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 35%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
}
  .plank {
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 10%;
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%; 
  } 
  .lock-screen {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
  }
</style>

<html>
  <body class="lock-screen" onload="init()">
    <div id="plank">
      <img class="plank" src="plank.png" ></img>
    </div>
    <div id="playarea" style="height:50%;width:50%;">
      <img class="drill" src="bulldog.gif" width="50%" id="bulldog" draggable="true" z-index="10"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="plankleft">
      <img class="plank" src="plankleft.png" ></img>
    </div>
    <div id="debug"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are the relevant parts of my javascript:

```
var audio;
document.ontouchend=function(){};
function init(){
    //set up event handlers
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, {passive: false});
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleStart);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleEnd, {passive: false});
}

function handleStart(){
    //set up movement handlers
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', drillMove, {passive: false});
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', drillMove, {passive: false});
}

function handleEnd(){
    //remove movement handlers
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drillMove, {passive: false});
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', drillMove, {passive: false});
}

//movement - this function doesn't get called on ios
function drillMove(e){
    //prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //position of touch or mouse
    let posX = 0;
    let posY = 0;

    //mouse
    if ((e.clientX)&&(e.clientY)) {
        posX = e.clientX;
        posY = e.clientY;
    }
    //touch
    else if (e.targetTouches) {
        posX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
        posY = e.targetTouches[0].clientY;
    }

    //drill element
    var drill = document.getElementById('bulldog');

    //current width of image - changes with window
    let w = document.getElementById('bulldog').width
    let stopratio = .22;

    //drill should move in the X axis where user wants until it hits the plank
    drill.style.left = Math.max((posX - w), window.innerWidth *.15) + 'px';
    drill.style.top = posY + 'px';

    //cut for time - put the hole on the plank etc etc 

    return false;
}
```

I have tried preventing the default like so:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

I have also tried looking at e.touches instead of e.targetTouches - no joy.

Thanks for any help. Hopefully, that is enough info.

edit:
My question was closed but the answer is not relevant. In my case touchmove is not called. The user in the other question needed to use e.originalEvent.touches, but their touchmove event handler was being called. That is not the case here.

edit 2:
My problem was solved by changing my init function like so:

```
function init(){
    //set up event handlers
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, {passive: false});
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleStart);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleEnd, {passive: false});
    //needed for ios
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', drillMove, {passive: false});
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iphone's safari touchmove event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531997/iphones-safari-touchmove-event-not-working)

Comment: Hello there, welcome to SO. Keep in mind to search first for your problem before asking. There are plenty of answers about these same problems you are having now.